# AWS Cognito UserPool Authentication on HTTP Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm building an API using the serverless framework. I'm trying to authenticate requests coming in through API Gateway by leveraging Cognito (UserPools), and giving each of my users their own authorization token for each API call they make.

Trying to test it with postman I'm not able to make a call and pass authorization. I've tried setting `Authorization` in the header with the `App Client Secret`, but I'm just getting "Unauthorized" back. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Post your current code and tell us what you have tried.

Comment: I'm trying through a postman request to get to the API Gateway/Lambda

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the token rather than the App Client Secret. How are you retrieving the token?

Comment: I'm not retrieving the token. My intention is to give to the token to my clients so they can just stuff it in their headers on all of their requests.

Comment: Ok, by default, sending the Authorization header requires an id token. The Client Secret is invalid for calling API Gateway. So if all you're trying to do is test, use the ID Token you retrieve from the token endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

For user sign in authorization, you must be sure you uncheck the option to generate client secret when you are creating a new Client Application inside UserPool.

In your API Gateway you create an authorizer making a reference to you before created UserPool. Inform "authorization" for the header.

Using a AWS third party SDK service (or just their API), signin with a valid user. You will get 2 types of tokens after the login, make sure you keep the right one. I advise you to check the token through the API Gateway authorizer testing option. Note: This step is the most important, as you are isolating the token you get and the authorization service. This way you can track the source of your problem.

Comment: The thing is that I don't have a log in. I want to give those using my service a token, so that they can authenticate on each API request. I would prefer to avoid them having to retrieve that token before making an API call, that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but I guess you are thinking a bit out of the authentication standards and your approach has security problems.
Would you mind sharing more details about your business solution and/or purpose?